# Теоретический вопрос (Delphi): Можно ли при компиляции конечного exe файла уменьшить его размер, если наследник TForm уберет некоторые ее свойства

Tags: delphi

:( Вот на школьной "олимпиаде" (не участвовал, но можно было решать задачи, часть теоретических) вытащил такой билет. И я не знаю как ответить, поможете?

"Теоретический вопрос (Delphi): Можно ли при компиляции конечного exe файла уменьшить его размер, если наследник TForm уберет некоторые ее свойства"

Про "уберет" ответов и задав вопрос - не нашел, может их можно удалить? или = nil?

Т.е. я так понимаю, что создаем класс

```
Uses Forms, Classes;

Type
tMyForm=Tform
//...??
```

// тут,.. не знаю, ну шрифт убрать, чтобы системный умолчальный был или прозрачность
    end;

```
var m:tMyform;
```

...

Знаний не много, что-то могу "написать",  но это.. в осадок выпал. Я знаю, что раньше для дельфи были компоненты вроде KOL(COL?) назывались? И там вроде на ассемблере часть кода была. Но сейчас, смотря на D 10.3 где для формы всякие есть прозрачности и шкуры... Не уверен уже. Т.е. наследника от тформ без зависимостей мелкого самого простого (ну пример просто форма с кнопкой ее закрытия) сделать не получится? :(
Если у вас есть время, можете пояснить?

Comment: поменяй да и нет местами "Можно ли ... уменьшить его размер?"© был вопрос, и продублируй его в конце

Comment: спасиб. вообще убрал, запутывает.

Comment: возможно имеется ввиду `override`?

Comment: а это уменьшит размер? в принципе не важно, что. т.е. е 1 exe где my=tform и 2 exe где my=tmyform. вот как последнюю меньше сделать? и возможно ли..

Comment: Нельзя. При компиляции, если вы используете TForm (например, наследуетесь от него), подключается юнит Vcl.Forms и все его зависимости. И чтобы вы в своём наследнике не "удалили", чтобы под этим не подразумевалось, Vcl.Forms как был, таким и останется, и слинкуется в exe в неизменном виде. Размер же вашего юнита зависит исключительно от размера кода, который вы там напишите, соответственно, только на это и можно повлиять.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Да, наследуюсь (+ответ от Qw..). Но если лишнее при наследовании "вырезать", то вступит в действие "оптимизатор компилятора", да, спорная штука, но она как бы лишние модули должна вырезать из финала при  релайзе (фри паскаль имею ввиду и тут также..наверное должно быть). я вот в таких глубоких познаниях не велик - но можете собрать стандартный exe в режиме релайз и после такой же с наследованием с вырезанием .. ну незнаю - чего либо из стандартной формы?

Comment: Что значит "вырезать" и откуда вдруг возьмутся "лишние" юниты? Код Vcl.Forms вы изменить не можете, значит все его юниты нужные.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Methods_(Delphi) ©It can also give the compiler hints that allow it to optimize the code it produces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Именно при компиляции нельзя. Если вы создадите пустую форму и посмотрите на DFM-файл, то свойств там будет не больше десятка, убирать нечего.

Если по простому, то основной размер - это предки `TForm`, начиная с `TObject` у них сотни свойств и методов и все они попадают в исполняемый файл, также как и зависимые объекты, которые форма использует. Каких-то специальных опций компилятора для исключения методов класса нет. Единственное компилятор сам исключает неиспользуемые классы и неиспользуемые необъектные функции.

*KOL* - не использовал *VCL*, можно считать, что он был написан с нуля, с меньшей глубиной наследования. Если, например, писать на чистом *WinAPI*, то программа будет вообще килобайты.

Можно уменьшить размер готового исполняемого файла, упаковав его специальными программами, но этим давно уже никто не занимается.

---

Upd: Немного в сторону от вопроса, но как напомнили в комментарии, что можно уменьшить размер (~5%), отключив формирование системной информации `RTTI` (опция `$WEAKLINKRTTI`).

---

Upd 06.05.2021

В Дельфи 2006 появилась директива компилятора под названием {$SETPEFLAGS}.
Она позволяет создание таблицы релокаций полностью отключить.

Но внимание! От таблицы ни в коем случае не отключайте релокаций в dll, bpl и иных файлах.

Сама же таблица релокации exe файлу и вовсе не нужна, потому что он грузится всегда по идентичному адресу.

Использование самой директивы {$SETPEFLAGS} достаточно простое:
Сначала откройте файл вашего проекта (dpr)
Далее добавьте в uses Windows
Продолжая, пропишите ниже {$SETPEFLAGS IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED}
Далее скомпилировать попробуйте файл именно до добавления данной директивы, а также и после.
После чего Вы убедитесь, что размер самой exe сразу уменьшился.

Для того, чтобы включить несколько инструкций, надо использовать or.

Вот пример:

```
{$SETPEFlAGS IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED or
IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED or
IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

- IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED – здесь отрезали релоки
- IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED – тут выбросил из ехе Debug саму информацию
- IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED – здесь выбросили из exe саму информацию о номерах строк
- IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED – тут выбросили local symbols
- IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP – Когда запускаете exe с компакта, флэшки, либо же других устройств, нужно считать exe в свап и именно оттуда запустить. Подойдет, когда необходимо с компакта запустить программу, а потом вставить другой попросить...
- IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP - идентично предыдущей, но предназначено исключительно для сетевых дисков.

Comment: т.е. отвечая на вопрос - нельзя ли что то вырезать при наследовании компонента (или даже если можно) - компилятор все равно включит все в сборку? не зависимо от опции компилятора (оптимизация - кста оч.давно посл. раз про нее читал про эмбаркадеро). Хорошо. А теоретически в FreePascal\Lazarus? (ответ принят, но хотел бы знать и "может быть") ++ "Можно уменьшить размер готового исполняемого файла, упаковав его специальными программами, но этим давно уже никто не занимается." - это ясно. ранее был mpack, сейчас только upx остался, и то, на каждую его 2ю сборку антивири бесятся :(

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ. Но тут в коментах огр. число символов, потому все не смог сказать..++ ошибся - mpack=>mpress (жаль, погиб проект) - гуглом. да, был еще aspack, тоже погиб, т.к. денег хотел

Comment: @Gu. Компилятор преобразует pas в dcu и включает его в exe. И если не ошибаюсь, из dcu он ничего не вырезает, какую бы оптимизацию вы не включили. Поэтому, даже если вы используете даже одну функцию из тысячи в данном юните, подключив его, вы получите всю тысячу в exe.

Comment: сообщение разобью, ограничение местное: не согласен. еще к delphi 7 читал описание формирования exe (конечно, такими знаниями как вы не похвастаюсь, но помню примерно, да из головы:)  "перед формированием dcu компилятор решает, включать или нет для компиляции во временный файл данные проекта, он учитывает включенные в него модули, а также учитывает опции компиляции, которые в свою очередь, могут влиять на процесс сборки.

Comment: Например некоторые модули, могут быть исключены из формирования проекта, если они в нем не были упомянуты".. Както так. ППц. почти дословно могу ..И далее по памяти "Исполняемый файл компилятора Pascal собирается линковщиком, формируя стандартный exe файл с учетом всех особенностей ОС, в которой он сформирован. При компиляции может быть использована оптимизация сборки, которая задается опциями в среде разработки".... Чтото-то типа .. Или уже все по другому?

Comment: Погуглил..Только сейчас начинаю понимать, на сколько отстал.. Но "Именно при компиляции нельзя" как ответ приму (хотя для free pascal готов обсуждать, но и там профан). Ясно, что переписывание кода - это не ответ". Всем спасибо.

Comment: Полностью не используемые объекты исключает, даже если они в одном DCU с используемым. А все что внутри объекта пихает.

Comment: спасибо  комрад  (комент алгоритм требует еще символов), добавлю плюсов +++ :)

Comment: "Каких-то специальных опций компилятора для исключения методов класса нет." `{$WEAKLINKRTTI ...}` например, плюс `{$RTTI ... }` с перекомпиляцией системных модулей, но это уже хак. Правда это опции линкера, а не компилятора, но смысл от этого не меняется.

Comment: Я все таки имел ввиду (и это следовало из вопроса) о функциональных методах, а не системных (RTTI). Но вы правы, так можно сократить размер, правда на не очень много (у меня было вроде около 5%).