# Delphi: Компиляция и лишнее в коде (uses и проч.)

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE. Есть некий модуль типов, скажем MyTypes.pas
В нем в секции типов описаны большинство типов D, примерно так MyByte=Byte; и проч. Но среди типов есть различия (редко).
Этот модуль тоже юзает некий модуль функций, с нужной функцией, которая тоже примерно так описана: MyFunc(const a:MyByte):Mybyte;
В обоих модулях - море других типов и функций.

Теперь, я в uses своего нового модуля пишу ссылку на нужную и использую эту функцию в своих недрах модуля.

Вопрос: вся вот эта ботва (лишние типы\процедуры\функции) затащится в исполняемый финальный модуль\код (только типом связанны)?

Если да, то можно ли как то отключить (в компиляторе опция оптимизации стоит)?
И как это проверить? Ранее вроде думал, что такое по умолчанию, но с объемами последних exe из последних версий Rad... уже думаю что нет.

Ну или другой пример, хотя, может тут другая логика.
Есть например модуль ZLib (стандартный из комплекта D).
Вот его например, если юзать в нескольких модулях (а он там еще obj тянет с собой) - это в exe будет как одна секция выглядеть (со всех, кто юзает - будет использование) или для каждого модуля своя будет (т.е. сколько запросил - столько получи)?

Comment: Юнит компилируется в dcu один раз (если этот юнит хоть где-то подключался в uses), а затем линкуется в exe тоже один раз. В новых версиях Delphi размер бинарника увеличивается из-за увеличения размера исходников системных юнитов.

Comment: [MapFileStats](https://www.delphitools.info/other-tools/mapfilestats/) - утилита, которая наглядно показывает сколько занимает тот или иной юнит в скомпилированном виде внутри exe.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Вам надо размер ЕХЕ сократить или лишние типы "убрать"? Подсказка, второе практически не расходует памяти.

Comment: >>не понятен. :: Мне нужно узнать (и желательно избавится в конечном exe)  -  входят ли в состав конечного exe все модули\косвенные  из подключаемого MyTypes (его и то, что он юзает - например, в нем объявлен тип условный из My.XXX.YYY - вот это будет в exe затащено? ); ||  Про ZLib - может плохо объяснил в примере.., простите. Вот например, в проге 2 юнита, в обоих есть uses Zlib. В exe попадет ссылка (нет, секция) на zlib 1 раз или 2? Т.е. размер увеличится? И при каждом новом модуле, кто zlib юзает - будет exe увеличиваться или компилятор будет ссылку делать на первое использование?

Answer (score 0):

В исполняемом файле, типы, функции присутствуют в одном экземпляре. Все, что не используется, в финальный файл не попадает. Простой эксперимент - это скомпилировать исходник с функцией, которую нигде не вызвать. Напротив строк этой функции не будет голубых точек, что показывает, что в исполняемый файл она не попала.

По поводу увеличение размера пустых проектов в новых версиях Delphi: это в большей степени связано с большой глубиной ООП. Используя `TForm` вы используете весь код её предков.

Посмотрите также этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1124081/365777).